# Failure jade with json - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - I can't find what's wrong

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I'm working on a project, in Node.js, express module, jade files, MongoDB-Mongoose and more..
I've a problem to implement json details from the database to the jade page.

I tried to figure out the problem, unsuccessfully.
I would like someone to help me find and fix it.
Thanks.

**That's the Error message:**

```
TypeError: /Users/itzhak/Desktop/Development/Porvivo/AWSporvivo/views/index.jade:66
   64|   div(id="archive-rooms-container" class="row panel thumbnail-row")
   65|     h4= 'Musical Projects'
 > 66|     each project, index in projects
   67|           div(class='col-md-3 rowSpace')
   68|               ul(class="room-details")
   69|                   li

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
   at jade_debug.unshift.lineno (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/itzhak/Desktop/Development/Porvivo/AWSporvivo/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:174:8), <anonymous>:618:31)
   at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/itzhak/Desktop/Development/Porvivo/AWSporvivo/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:174:8), <anonymous>:815:4)
   at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/itzhak/Desktop/Development/Porvivo/AWSporvivo/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:174:8), <anonymous>:955:22)
   at res (/Users/itzhak/Desktop/Development/Porvivo/AWSporvivo/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:175:38)
   at Object.exports.render (/Users/itzhak/Desktop/Development/Porvivo/AWSporvivo/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:300:10)
   at Object.exports.renderFile (/Users/itzhak/Desktop/Development/Porvivo/AWSporvivo/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:336:18)
   at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/itzhak/Desktop/Development/Porvivo/AWSporvivo/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:321:21)
   at View.render (/Users/itzhak/Desktop/Development/Porvivo/AWSporvivo/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:93:8)
   at EventEmitter.app.render (/Users/itzhak/Desktop/Development/Porvivo/AWSporvivo/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:530:10)
   at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/itzhak/Desktop/Development/Porvivo/AWSporvivo/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:933:7)
```

> Jade code:

```
each project, index in projects
      div(class='col-md-3 rowSpace')
          ul(class="room-details")
              li
                  a(href="/projects/" + project.sessionId id=project.sessionId)
                      h3(style='margin:0 0 3px')= project.projectName
              - var playerNames = [];
              - for(var playerIndex in project.players) playerNames.push(room.players[playerIndex].name);
              li
                  for playerName in playerNames
                      a(href="../" + playerName)= playerName
          a(href="/projects/" + project.sessionId id=project.sessionId): img(src=project.img class="img-responsive")
```

> Js code (on client side):

```
function loadProjects() {
    $.getJSON('/projects/info', function( data ) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    loadProjects();
    setInterval(loadProjects, 10000);
});
```

> app code: (node.js)

```
var express = require('express'),
router = express.Router(),
Project = require('../schemas/project'),
projects = [];

Project.find().lean().exec(function(err, items) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('* ERROR!!! : ' + err);
        } else {
            projects = items;
            console.log('* SUCCESS : ' + JSON.stringify(projects));
        }
    });

    router.get('/info', function(req, res) {
        res.json({projects: projects});
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks a lot!

Itzhak.

Comment: projects is undefined

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, 
The jade is rendered on server while i tried to get details to the jade from the JS on client side.
I fixed it by render the details directly from the server because it's more suitable my needs but there's another option, send just an empty template jade to client and insert details to html by JS.

Hope this gonna help someone someday :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know Jade, but the problem seems to come from the data.

It seems *projects* is undefined so the parser cannot read it (I guess it tries to get its length before looping through its children, and an error is thrown).

So the first thing to do would be to check the data you receive from the database.

Comment: I'm checking it. I'll tell you if this will be solved. Thanks